# Combine all columns of a data.frame in a single one (vector concatenation)

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations, multiple-columns

I want to convert this data.frame

```
C1  C2  C3  C4
q   t   p   k   
g   l   i   y
f   d   t   r
```

to a data.frame with *a single column* with this order of  elements `q,t,p,k,g,l,i,y,f,d,t,r`. Note that **it is not a concatenation of columns.**

Result:

```
C1
q
t
p
k
l
i
y
f
d
t
r
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can transpose the `data.frame` to a `matrix`, concatenate to convert it to `vector` and create a single column `data.frame`

```
data.frame(C1 = c(t(df)))
#   C1
#1   q
#2   t
#3   p
#4   k
#5   g
#6   l
#7   i
#8   y
#9   f
#10  d
#11  t
#12  r
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = c("q", "g", "f"), C2 = c("t", "l", "d"), 
C3 = c("p", "i", "t"), C4 = c("k", "y", "r")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: So, the result is the concatenation of the columns of the matrix transposed. But you do the concatenation converting it to a vector and finally to a data.frame. Thank you.